# What's going on with this SOA graph?

Tags: datasheet, safe-operating-area, breakdown

[image]
Above is a screenshot of the SOA graph from the [GAN041-WSB350 datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/GAN041-650WSB.pdf).

When I saw this, I immediately got very curious, because I'm used to seeing SOA graphs where all the lines on the top right are parallel and either straight lines (for devices that don't suffer from second breakdown) or with a single bend (for devices that have second breakdown). I've certainly never seen concave portions of the graph!

[image][image]

These images (from the [MSC080SMA120B datasheet](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_download/1243494-msc080sma120b-datasheet) and the [2N5883 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n5883-d.pdf) respectively) are representative of what I expect an SOA graph to look like--so what on earth is going on with this GaN device?

I would assume it's something to do with it being a GaN device, but it's clearly more than just the fact that it's a wide-bandgap semiconductor--the first of my examples of a normal-looking SOA graph is a SiC part, and that looks identical to any old silicon MOSFET's SOA. I know GaN parts typically can't handle avalanche at all; is that one of the limiting factors making the odd shapes? Even if so, what are all the other limiting factors? This graph just looks so bizarre.

Comment: I have a feeling that fig 11 in the GaN device might be a decent clue. On the other hand, I never believe pure straight line graphs for regular MOSFETs because of thermal runaway at lower gate-source voltages.

Comment: A GaN device is comprised of an enhancement MOSFET and a depletion GaN part - I wonder if that causes the unusual SOA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some comparing of properties of silicon mosfets to GaN (capacitances, package properties, thermal properties). I could find no real differences except one.

I also found that all 'regular' silicon mosfets have a similarly shaped SOA to each other, there are two methods to find SOA one is calculated and the other is measured (not all manufactures measure SOA some calculate it based off of other specs, [TI has been measuring since 2014](https://training.ti.com/understanding-mosfet-datasheets-safe-operating-area-soa), but the measured SOAs for a regular mosfet look like the calculated values and all silicon mosfets have similar curves).

Another interesting fact the SOA for other GaNs look similar (this GaN part has almost all or very similar specs to the one in the OP) and also has that weird SOA curve:

[image]
https://www.transphormusa.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/tp65h035wsqa_v1-1.pdf

This means the problem is most likely related the properties of a GaN, but what?

The main difference I could find when comparing datasheets is the "Transient thermal impedance from junction to mounting base" as a function of pulse duration" This is an example from a/the GaN device:
[image]
Source: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/GAN041-650WSB.pdf

Transient thermal impedance from junction to mounting base is the thermal resistance and mass that impedes heat from moving from the die to the case. We want heat to move to the case (and then to a heatsink, pcb or air) to keep the temperature down.

> A device subjected to a power pulse of duration > ~1 second, i.e.
> steady-state, has reached thermal equilibrium and the Zth plateaus
> becomes the Rth. The Zth illustrates the fact that materials have
> thermal inertia. Thermal inertia means that temperature does not
> change instantaneously. As a result, the device can handle greater
> power for shorter duration pulses

Source: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/application-note/AN11261.pdf

This is an example from a regular silicon device.
[image]
Source: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PSMN057-200P.pdf

A normal Fet has better thermal conductivity (these graphs are hard to compare so I pulled out some 'rough' values)

A single pulse with a  1ms duration has 0.11K/W for silicon and 0.2K/W for GaN
A single pulse with a 10ms duration has 0.3 K/W for silicon and 0.6K/W for GaN
A duty cycle of \$\delta=0.1\$ with a 1ms duration has 0.15K/W for silicon and 0.2K/W for GaN

The GaN is about half as good as silicon at moving heat out from the die to the package with shorter pulses where \$\delta<0.5\$. This could be from many factors but I suspect it is from device construction.

GaN as a material has similar thermal conductivity to silicon (and has better properties than silicon in everything else except electron mobility, which probably has no bearing on how much heat a device can handle).

I don't think its the material properties in and of themselves that would drive the differences in thermal impedance so it is more likely that it is the construction of the device:

[image]
Source: https://spectrum.ieee.org/semiconductors/materials/gallium-oxide-power-electronics-cool-new-flavor

Another interesting thing to note is the GaN's seem to be worse in the thermal stability region, which means for longer pulses and higher Vds voltages they are more prone to get into a thermal runaway situation. I think this could correlate with the difference in thermal performance at short duration's and is probably the answer, but there probably won't be a infinitive answer without talking to a designer, or dencapsulating\reverse engineering devices.

[image]
Source: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/posts/understanding-mosfet-data-sheets-part-2-safe-operating-area-soa-graph

And another interesting graph is for an SiC device, I didn't delve into it but it has *a similar SOA and junction to case thermal impedance* as a silicon device.

[image]
Source: https://www.wolfspeed.com/media/downloads/1628/C3M0060065D.pdf

## Edit (the internet continues to astound me):

I did find pics of a teardown for the part in the same family, the  GAN063-650WSA! ( and same package which means the looks similar or maybe exactly the same)!

[image]
Source: https://www.systemplus.fr/reverse-costing-reports/nexperias-aec-q101-qualified-650-v-gan-based-power-device/

The GaN is cascoded, so it is actually two FETs

[image]
Source: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/GAN041-650WSB.pdf

For a single FET

[image]

Both the cascode\silicon FET and the GAN FET generate heat with their bulk resistivity, and this heat has to move toward the gate.
The heat from the silicon FET has more material that it needs to pass through to reach the heatsink (the epoxy is not as good at conducting heat). This results in two slopes of the SOA graph. The silicon cascode FET will also likely be one of the hottest areas in the device. (which makes me wonder if cascoded GaN isn't really that competitive as a switching device as the SiC device listed in this question has no such limits. It also makes me wonder if there aren't ways to improve GaN.

However, I did find some SiC FETS that (are advertised as) are cascoded, but they have no weird SOA (That device is here: https://unitedsic.com/datasheets/DS_UJ3C120040K3S.pdf), I didn't find the construction of that device, but in the end I think it's construction more than anything that determines the SOA along with the thermal stackup.

[image]
Source: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00241971-thermal-effects-and-junction-temperature-evaluation-of-power-mosfets-stmicroelectronics.pdf

The link above is a really good read if you ever need to do modeling on FET thermal internals.

Comment: I think GaN parts are generally constructed on top of a silicon substrate, so I wonder how much of their weird thermal properties comes from thermal mismatch between the GaN and Si... Thank you for the very detailed answer! I'm going to give it a bit before I accept or award the bounty but this has answered most of my questions about the strange SOA. You wouldn't happen to know what the limiting factors are on the different parts of the curve, would you?

Comment: Looking at the thermal numbers, GaN are close to silicon, and I also think they must be built in silicon. I'm also thinking that the additional layers that must be used for the additonal mosfet for the cascade might drive the weird shape of the SOA curve. But the cascode is not limited to only GaN parts, similar tech could be applied to SiC, the cree\wolfspeed part that is posted at the bottom also uses license patents from nexperia (but says nothing about using cascode), trying to find out the construction will be more difficult because the manufacturers don't really publish this info

Comment: I know I've seen some cascode SiC parts, but they don't seem to be as common anymore, as they've figured out how to make enhancement-mode SiC MOSFETs that work just like silicon parts, with no silicon involved. I imagine the cascode with a SiC JFET may have been used before they had figured out a good way to grow oxide (or nitride, or whatever they use) on SiC, perhaps?

Comment: @Hearth I did find a picture of the FET (or one in the family right next to it), it is cascoded and the SOA is from the materials and cascoding that you end up with the funky SOA graph.

Answer (score 4):

This thing isn't just a MOSFET...

[image]

It's a low voltage MOSFET with a JFET cascode on top.

I guess the MOSFET alone would have a SOA like the blue lines I added or something similar:

[image]

From the other graphs in the datasheet it has strong negative tempco on thershold voltage (hotter = increased current) which is what triggers Spirito instability (hotspot gets more current and heats even more).

But the cascode limits internal MOSFET Vds, so when Vds for the whole device rises, Vds for the internal MOSFET should remain pretty low. So that would "stretch" the SOA graph along the voltage axis, as the graph shows.

The cascode JFET also has a SOA, so the result is a mix of both.

This is mostly a guess, so... grain of salt.